# CQL select showing encoded values

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am new to cassandra and trying my hands on basic commands. The following is how I am inserting using cassandra-cli

```
set contactManagementSystem['rowkey3']['firstName'] ='xyz';set contactManagementSystem['rowkey3']['lastName'] ='abc';
```

but when i try to view those values on CQLSH this is what it shows:

```
cqlsh:test> select * from "contactManagementSystem";

 key              | column1                  | value
-----+-

 0x726f776b657933 |     0x66697273744e616d65 |                 0x41616b61

 0x726f776b657933 |       0x6c6173744e616d65 |                       0x4d

 0x726f776b657933 |             0x70686f6e65 |   0x3631372d3132332d373839
```

I just wanted to understand why is it happening like this and what am I doing wrong? (apologies for the weird looking code. I do not have enough reputations to post images)

Answer (score 1):

While creating table/columnfamily using cassandra-cli the default datatype of columns will be BytesType. So when you describe/select the data it will show you in bytes format. But you can declare the datatype for columns while creating column family.

You can find it [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/use_create_table_t.html)

Also you can create column family using CQLSH as well, and you can declare [datatype](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html) for each column. [Here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/create_table_t.html) you can find how to create table/column family using cqlsh.

And doing CRUD using CQLSH is very simple.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I should have mentioned, after creating the column-family i noticed the byte type and wrote the following code to change it:

ASSUME contactManagementSystem KEYS AS ascii;
ASSUME contactManagementSystem COMPARATOR AS ascii;
ASSUME contactManagementSystem VALIDATOR AS ascii;

I hoped that would help.